# Flatten double-linked list

Tags: python, interview-questions, linked-list

> Consider this interview question:
>
> Given a Node with a reference to a child, its next, its previous, and a variable for its value (\$\frac{1}{2}\$ tree, \$\frac{1}{2}\$ doubly linked list structure), you have to find a way to flatten the structure.
>
> ```
> 1 = 2 = 3 = 5
>     |       |
>     6 = 7   8
>         |
>         9
> ```
>
> (reference down is child and reference across is next)
>
> this above diagram becomes: 1 - 2 - 6 - 7- 9 - 3 - 5 - 8 but:
>
> - 2 still has child reference to 6
> - 7 still has child reference to 9
> - 5 still has child reference to 8

Here is my code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None, prev=None, child=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_node
        self.prev = prev
        self.child = child

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

one = Node(1)
two = Node(2)
three = Node(3)
five = Node(5)
six = Node(6)
seven = Node(7)
eight = Node(8)
nine = Node(9)
one.next = two
two.prev = one
two.next = three
two.child = six
three.prev = two
three.next = five
five.prev = three
five.child = eight
six.next = seven
seven.prev = six
seven.child = nine

def flatten(head):
    if not head: return head

    c = flatten(head.child) 
    n = flatten(head.next)
    if c:
        head.next = head.child
        head.child.prev = head
    if c and n:
        tail = c
        while tail.next:
            tail = tail.next
        tail.next = n
        n.prev = tail
    return head

n = flatten(one)
while n:
    print "%d -" % (n.value,),
    n = n.next
```

I don't like the while loop. I could store tail and pass it around. Any better solution?

Comment: Welcome on CodeReivew.SE! Out of curiosity, what is supposed to be the logic to flatten a structure which cannot be flatten in an obvious way? Is the stategy always to apply "child first" ? Also, you might want your `Node` class to handle the fact that when `i.next` is `j` then `j.prev` is `i` in order not to have to set the two relations manually.

Comment: I found this interview question in the interwebz. I think we can assume that there are no cycles or any corner cases. Good idea with `link` function.

Comment: Why is the expected answer "1 - 2 - 6 - 7- 9 - 3 - 5 - 8" and not "1-2-3-5-8-6-7-9"

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation is quite nice.

The only way you are going to avoid using the `while` loop to find the right-most node is if you have each individual branch maintain its branch's tail `Node`. This is a [sort of] good approach to the problem. However, once you reach this point, a `Node` really starts becoming more than just a `Node`: it now has information about the entire structure instead of what is directly around it.

So instead of modifying the `Node` class, you could create a `Tree` class.

This change makes sense:

1. Right now you manually create your 'tree'. This approach is not very portable. A `Tree` class can handle its own creation.
2. You need to store information about the entire branch structure somewhere. Inside a `Node` doesn't feel right.
3. You don't really flatten a `Node`, you flatten a **tree** of nodes. Thus, it again makes sense to move the `flatten` function inside a `Tree` class (or at least take a `Tree` parameter).

Here is a skeleton version of my `Tree` class. I have stubbed out all my methods except `flatten` as that is the function in question:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root
        self.tail = root        
        self.length = 1 if root else 0

    def __iter__(self):
        ''' Allows iteration through the tree using `for node in tree`. '''
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ''' Fetches the `Node` at the passed index. '''
        pass

    def grow(self, nodes):
        ''' Appends node/nodes/Tree onto itself. Be careful when adding `Node`
            we need to append a *copy* of a `Node`, not the reference. '''
        pass

    def graft(self, tree, node_pos=0):
        ''' Grafts in another tree to this one. By default the new tree
            is grafted to the root of the tree. '''
        pass

    def flatten(self):
        ''' Returns the flattened version of itself. '''
        flat = Tree()
        for next in self:
            flat.grow(next)
            if next.child:
                flat.grow(next.child.flatten())
        return flat
```

In this version of `flatten`, we keep the recursive feel as we call a method with the same method declaration. However, we are not doing true recursion because the methods are bound to different objects, and thus are different methods.

In any case, the `flatten` function is really quite simple:

1. Create the new `Tree` we are going to modify and return.
2. Loop through the `Node`s of the current tree.
3. Append the current `Node`.

   3.1. If that `Node` has a child `Tree`, append the flattened version of that `Tree`.
4. Return the final flattened `Tree`.

Here is my `Tree` class plus your `Node` class in action:

```
one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = [Node(num) for num in xrange(1,10)]

tree = Tree(one)
tree.grow([two, three, five])

# Graft the new `Tree` to the 3rd `Node`.
tree.graft(Tree(eight), 3)

branch = Tree(six)
branch.grow(seven)

# Graft the new `Tree` to the 1st `Node`.
branch.graft(Tree(nine), 1)

tree.graft(branch, 1)

def flatten(tree):
    ''' A non-class version of the `flatten` function. '''
    flat = Tree()
    for next in tree:
        flat.grow(next)
        if next.child:
            flat.grow(flatten(next.child))
    return flat


print ' - '.join([str(node.value) for node in flatten(tree)])
print ' - '.join([str(node.value) for node in tree.flatten()])
```